# When token has a value,it take the first object of header in DioFactory Class !and when call any api use this token , it can not take the token Why?

Tags: flutter, api, mvvm, dependency-injection, token

First , i am using MVVM

[i made a DioFactory class for get dio object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QXHd.png)

[This class for dependency injection and i call the initialAppModuleClass() before the runApp method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkgiQ.png)

[This class for route Generator and i call the dependency injection method for every page before build it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKWpq.png)

[This For App Preferences for data in shared Preference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0MoyG.png)

[When login is success i store the token in shared Preference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZI2O.png)

When go to home screen and i called any api with token it not work , it did not get the token it still empty although it store in shared preference and take the first object of _headers in dio .

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are intializing the token when create the Dio Factory
Even if the token in sharedPrefs is changed but still the value in Dio factory as the first time you added.
The soluation is pass the token for the api header
if you are using retrofit package you can do this
`@Header("user-token") String token`
then in api call you can use the sharedprefs to pass token to the header